# Is something similar to ServiceLoader in Java 1.5?

Tags: java, reflection, plugins, service

How do I discover classes at runtime in the classpath which implements a defined interface?

ServiceLoader suits well (I think, I haven't used it), but I need do it in Java 1.5.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There's nothing built into Java 1.5 for this. I implemented it myself; it's not too complicated. However, when we upgrade to Java 6, I will have to replace calls to my implementation with calls to `ServiceLoader`. I could have defined a little bridge between the app and the loader, but I only use it in a few places, and the wrapper itself would be a good candidate for a ServiceLoader.

This is the core idea:

```
public <S> Iterable<S> load(Class<S> ifc) throws Exception {
  ClassLoader ldr = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
  Enumeration<URL> e = ldr.getResources("META-INF/services/" + ifc.getName());
  Collection<S> services = new ArrayList<S>();
  while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
    URL url = e.nextElement();
    InputStream is = url.openStream();
    try {
      BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
      while (true) {
        String line = r.readLine();
        if (line == null)
          break;
        int comment = line.indexOf('#');
        if (comment >= 0)
          line = line.substring(0, comment);
        String name = line.trim();
        if (name.length() == 0)
          continue;
        Class<?> clz = Class.forName(name, true, ldr);
        Class<? extends S> impl = clz.asSubclass(ifc);
        Constructor<? extends S> ctor = impl.getConstructor();
        S svc = ctor.newInstance();
        services.add(svc);
      }
    }
    finally {
      is.close();
    }
  }
  return services;
}
```

Better exception handling is left as an exercise for the reader. Also, the method could be parameterized to accept a ClassLoader of the caller's choosing.

Answer (score 6):

`javax.imageio.spi.ServiceRegistry` is the equivalent with prior Java versions. It's available since Java 1.4.

It does not look like a general utility class, but it is. It's even a bit more powerful than `ServiceLoader`, as it allows some control over the order of the returned providers and direct access to the registry.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?javax/imageio/spi/ServiceRegistry.html

Answer (score 1):

ServiceLoader is quite basic, and has been in use (informally) within the JDK since 1.3. ServiceLoader just finally made it a first class citizen. It simply looks for a resource file named for your interface, which is basically bundled in the META-INF directory of a library jar.

That file contains the name of the class to load.

So, you'd have a file named:

META-INF/services/com.example.your.interface

and inside it is a single line: com.you.your.interfaceImpl.

In lieu of ServiceLoader, I like Netbeans Lookup. It works with 1.5 (and maybe 1.4).

Out of the box, it does the exact same thing as ServiceLoader, and it's trivial to use. But it offers a lot more flexibility.

Here's a link: http://openide.netbeans.org/lookup/

Here's a article about ServiceLoader, but it mentions Netbeans Lookup at the bottom:
http://weblogs.java.net/blog/timboudreau/archive/2008/08/simple_dependen.html

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately,

> There's nothing built into Java 1.5 for this ...

is only a part of truth.

There is non-standard `sun.misc.Service` around.

http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/sun/misc/Service.html

Beware, it is not a part of standard J2SE API! 
It is non-standard part of Sun JDK. 
So you can not rely on it if you use, say, `JRockit`.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but the other option is to use **Package Level Annotations**.
See my answer for: [Find Java classes implementing an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/435890/find-java-classes-implementing-an-interface/5831808#5831808)

Package level annotations are annotations that are in package-info.java classes.

JAXB uses this instead of Service Loaders. I also think its more flexible than the service loader.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reliable way to know what classes are in the classpath. According to its [documentation](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html), ServiceLoader relies on external files to tell it what classes to load; you might want to do the same. The basic idea is to have a file with the name of the class(es) to load, and then use reflection to instantiate it/them.