# Get concrete Class realization from interface reference

Tags: java, inheritance

Is it possible in java to obtain `ConcreetClass.class` from interface reference `ISomeInterface`. I would like to avoid 'instance of' keyword.
On other words, is there:

```
ISomeInterface intRef = new ConcreetClass();
Class realization = intRef.getRealizationClass();
realization == ConcreetClass.class; // true
```

If java doesn't support this operation. Could you recommend me a way to deal with it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get a list of all the implementations of an interface programmatically in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/347248/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-the-implementations-of-an-interface-programmatically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getClass` returns the `class` of the `instance`.

```
Class<? extends ISomeInterface> realization = intRef.getClass();
System.out.println(ConcreetClass.class.equals(realization)); //true
```

Comment: Is there also a way to downcast `realization` to the concrete class with this?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get the specific class of any object using the `getClass()` method.