# Creating an Hierarchy-Object with an undefined number of childs

Tags: java, hierarchy

I am currently working on a "code parser" parsing Valve Map Format (.vmf files) into a java readable Object.

In vmf files,

- there are 2 types of objects: Classes and Properties.
- classes have a name and can contain other classes and properties.
- properties have a name and an unlimited number of values.

Therefore I created a `VMFClass` Object Class and a `VMFProperty` Object Class.
I created a List with self-created `HierarchyObject`s, containing the `VMFClass`/`VMFProperty` Object, an UUID and the parentUUID.
The `VMFClass` Object Contains 2 Lists one with sub-`VMFClass`es, one with properties.

My Problem is that I have no clue on how to achieve that a Class contains all of its subclasses, since I can't tell how much subclasses the subclasses have and so on...

Here is my Code ([Github](https://github.com/RoiEXLab/SourceCraftReloaded/tree/master/src/net/minecraft/sourcecraftreloaded/source)):

`HierachyObject`:

```
package net.minecraft.sourcecraftreloaded.utils;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class HierarchyObject {
    private static Map<Long, Long> usedUUIDs = new HashMap<>();
    private long parentUUID;
    private long UUID;
    private Object object;

    /**
     * 
     * @param Object
     * @param parent -1 is maximum level
     */
    public HierarchyObject(Object object, long parent) {
        this.object = object;
        this.parentUUID = parent;
        while (true) {
            long random = (long) (Math.random() * Long.MAX_VALUE);
            if (usedUUIDs.containsKey(random)) {
                this.UUID = random;
                usedUUIDs.put(random, parent);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public long getUUID() {
        return UUID;
    }
    public long getParentUUID() {
        return parentUUID;
    }

    public static long getParentUUIDbyUUID(long UUID) {
        if (usedUUIDs.containsKey(UUID)) {
            return usedUUIDs.get(UUID);
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public Object getObject() {
        return object;
    }

    public static boolean hasChild(long UUID){
        if(usedUUIDs.containsValue(UUID)){
            return true;
        }
        if(UUID == -1){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean hasChild(){
        return hasChild(this.UUID);
    }

    public static long[] getChildUUIDs(long UUID){
        if(hasChild(UUID)){
            List<Long> cUUIDs = new ArrayList<>();
            for(int i = 0; i < usedUUIDs.size(); i++){
                for (Map.Entry<Long, Long> e : usedUUIDs.entrySet()) {
                    if(e.getValue().longValue() == UUID){
                        cUUIDs.add(e.getKey());
                    }
                }
            }
            return ListUtils.toPrimitivebyList(cUUIDs);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

`VMFProperty`:

```
package net.minecraft.sourcecraftreloaded.source;

public class VMFProperty{

    private String name;
    private String[] values;

    public VMFProperty(String name, String... values) {
        this.name = name;
        this.values = values;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public String[] getValues() {
        return values;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object paramObject){
        if(paramObject instanceof VMFProperty){
            return ((VMFProperty)paramObject).name.equals(this.name) && ((VMFProperty)paramObject).values.equals(this.values);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

`VMFClass`:

```
package net.minecraft.sourcecraftreloaded.source;

import java.util.List;

public class VMFClass{
    private List<VMFClass> classes;
    private List<VMFProperty> properties;
    private String name;

    public VMFClass(String name, List<VMFClass> classes, List<VMFProperty> properties) {
        this.name = name;
        this.classes = classes;
        this.properties = properties;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public List<VMFClass> getClasses() {
        return classes;
    }
    public List<VMFProperty> getProperties() {
        return properties;
    }
    public void add(VMFClass vmfclass) {
        classes.add(vmfclass);
    }
    public void add(VMFProperty vmfproperty) {
        properties.add(vmfproperty);
    }
    public void remove(VMFClass vmfclass) {
        classes.remove(vmfclass);
    }
    public void remove(VMFProperty vmfproperty) {
        properties.remove(vmfproperty);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object paramObject){
        if(paramObject instanceof VMFClass){
            return ((VMFClass)paramObject).properties.equals(this.properties) && ((VMFClass)paramObject).classes.equals(this.classes) && ((VMFClass)paramObject).name.equals(this.name);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

`VMFObject` (the class executing all the code):

```
package net.minecraft.sourcecraftreloaded.source;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import net.minecraft.sourcecraftreloaded.utils.HierarchyObject;

public class VMFObject {
    private String rawfile = "";
    private List<VMFClass> toplevelclasses;

    private static final String INVALID_CHARS = "\\*,;<>|?=`´#'+~^°!§$%&()[].:-_";

    public VMFObject(List<VMFClass> toplevelclasses) {
        this.toplevelclasses = toplevelclasses;
    }

    public VMFObject() {
        this(new ArrayList<VMFClass>());
    }

    public void write(File file) {
        VMFWriter.write(file, rawfile);
    }

    public VMFObject read(File file) throws VMFParsingException {
        this.rawfile = VMFReader.read(file);
        parse();
        return this;
    }
    public List<VMFClass> getClasses() {
        return toplevelclasses;
    }

    private void parse() throws VMFParsingException {
        evaluate();
        get();
    }

    private void evaluate() throws VMFParsingException {
        char[] textchars = rawfile.toCharArray();
        int[] c = new int[]{0, 0, 0};
        int line = 0;
        int linepos = 0;
        for (int i : textchars) {
            linepos++;
            if (textchars[i] == '\n') {
                line++;
                linepos = 0;
                c[3] = 0;
                if (c[3] % 2 != 0) {
                    throw new VMFParsingException("Invalid quotes on line" + line + ":" + linepos);
                }
            }
            if (textchars[i] == '{') {
                c[1]++;
            }
            if (textchars[i] == '}') {
                c[2]++;
            }
            if (textchars[i] == '"') {
                c[3]++;
                if (c[1] - c[2] == 0) {

                }
            }
            if (textchars[i] == '/' && textchars[i + 1] == '/') {
                while (true) {
                    i++;
                    if (textchars[i] == '\n') {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (textchars[i] == '/' && textchars[i + 1] == ' ') {
                throw new VMFParsingException("Invalid Character '/' on line" + line + ":" + linepos);
            }
            if (INVALID_CHARS.indexOf(textchars[i]) != -1) {
                throw new VMFParsingException("Invalid Character '" + textchars[i] + "' on line" + line + ":" + linepos);
            }
        }
        if (c[1] != c[2]) {
            throw new VMFParsingException("Unbalanced brackets in vmf File");
        }
    }

    public void add(VMFClass vmfclass) {
        toplevelclasses.add(vmfclass);
    }

    private void get() throws VMFParsingException {
        List<HierarchyObject> content = new ArrayList<>();
        long curparent = -1;
        String[] text = rawfile.split("\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
            String line = text[i].trim();
            if (line.startsWith("//")) {
                continue;
            } else {
                byte quotec = 0;
                char[] linechar = line.toCharArray();
                boolean readp = false;
                List<String> reads = new ArrayList<>();
                byte creads = 0;
                for (int y = 0; y < linechar.length; y++) {
                    if (linechar[y] == '/' && linechar[y + 1] == '/') {
                        break;
                    }
                    if (linechar[y] == '"') {
                        quotec++;
                        if (quotec % 2 == 0) {
                            readp = false;
                            creads++;
                        } else {
                            readp = true;
                        }
                    }
                    if (readp) {
                        reads.set(creads, reads.get(creads) + linechar[y]);
                    }
                    if (linechar[y] == '{') {
                        HierarchyObject object = new HierarchyObject(new VMFClass(line.substring(line.substring(0, y).lastIndexOf(' '), y).trim(), null, null), curparent);
                        content.add(object);
                        curparent = object.getUUID();
                    }
                    if (linechar[y] == '}') {
                        curparent = HierarchyObject.getParentUUIDbyUUID(curparent);
                    }

                }
                content.add(new HierarchyObject(new VMFProperty(reads.remove(0), reads.toArray(new String[reads.size()])), curparent));
            }
        }
        buildObject(content);
    }

    private void buildObject(List<HierarchyObject> content) {
        long curUUID = -1;
        for(int i = 0; i < HierarchyObject.getChildUUIDs(curUUID).length; i++){
            HierarchyObject.getChildUUIDs(curUUID);
        }
        //TODO implement
    }
}
```

the //TODO part is where the Hierachy Object should get "converted" to the actual object.

Comment: Parser generator like ANTLR4 is perfect for stuff like this, but that aside - why do you need a hierarchy object? Can't a VMFClass simply have pointer (dare I use c++ term:) to it's "parent" object and have a collection of child VMFClasses and a collection of VMFProperties?

Comment: ANTLR4 looks good to me will eventually look into that later... basically taht's what I want, but the thing is, since those child classes can have other child classes we are back at my question... how do I achieve this?

Comment: What I wrote in the first comment: just add `protected VMFClass parent;` to VMFClass.java. If it's *null* it means that it's root. I'm assuming that the `private List<VMFClass> classes;` is a collection of child classes. I'm also assuming that by *classes* you are referring to parsed entities and not java classes?

Comment: I already know which vmfclass has which parent using the hierarchy object... I need a way to call the childs of a specific class in order to write all of the classes in it's hierarchy into a file

Comment: Let's set aside all other weird code - not our concern. Basically you need some sort of tree structure. A tree node could be your HierarchyObject, but it's lacking necessary methods to get its's children or parent. Add these methods or switch to use classes in javax.swing.tree (these classes are for generic uses, not only for Java Swing).

Comment: BTW, I don't quite understand how your UUID (if it is really a RFC 4122 UUID) system works. Maybe you want use them to locate a node, but then you are lacking a registry, and that's really not a good coding style in OOP. It's like simulating the task of a java runtime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Overview

It seems to me that your class layout is overcomplicated.

Let's try to simplify it...

What you have described with the VMF model is essentially a <s>linked-list</s> Tree.

Here's what the model looks like:

```
                    [.vmf file] (root)
                       /    \
                 _____/      \ _____
                /                   \                
               /                     \
           (VMFClass)               (VMFClass)
             /     \                   /    \
            /       \                 /      \
           /         \               /        \
      (VMFClass)   (VMFProperties) (VMFClass)  (VMFProperties)    
       /      \                    
      /        \                
     /          \
 (VMFClass)   (VMFProperties)
```

**What you need**:

- A Parser class (in your case, you have `VMFObject`, but lets call this class `VMFParser`).
- The `VMFClass` and `VMFProperty` classes which you have are fine.

**What you don't need**:

- The `HierarchyObject` class. The `VMFParser` can be the main controller and container for the hierarchy (e.g. the <s>linked-list</s> Tree model).
- All the UUIDs (parent, child, etc.) These are just complicated things, but I see why you have them. You don't need them to track the hierarchy - Java will do this for us!!

### VMFClass

```
public class VMFClass
{
    // name of the class
    private String name;

    // reference back up to the parent
    private VMFClass parentClass = null;

    // all direct children go here
    private List<VMFClass> children = new ArrayList<VMFClass>(); 

    // I don't think you need a list of properties here since your VMFProperty class holds onto an array of properties
    private VMFProperty properties;

    // set the parent of this class
    public void setParent (VMFClass parent)
    {
        this.parentClass = parent;
    }

    // get the direct children
    public List<VMFClass> getChildren()
    {
        return this.children;
    }

    // rest of methods...
}
```

### VMFParser

```
class VMFParser
{
    private String rawfile = "";

    // this is really the container for everything - think of it as the file shell
    private VMFClass root = new VMFClass("root", null, null);

    // construct yourself with the file
    public VMFParser (String fileName)
    {
        this.rawfile = fileName;
    }

    public void parse ()
    {
        // all the parsing code goes here
        read();
        evaluate();
        get();

        // now at this point your hierarchy is built and stored in the   
        // root object in this class.

        // Use the traverse method to go through it
    }

    private void get() throws VMFParsingException
    {
        // keep a reference to the current VMFClass parent
        // starts out as root
        VMFClass currParentClass = root;

        // main parse loop
        for (...)
        {
            // if you find a class
            VMFClass currClass = new VMFClass(/* params here */);

            // add this class to the parent
            currParentClass.add(currClass);

            // set the parent of this class
            currClass.setParent(currParentClass);

            // if you find a property
            // parse and add all the properties to the property
            VMFProperty property = new VMFProperty (/* value params here */);

            // attach this property to the last VMF class that got parsed
            currClass.setPoperties(property);

            // If you nest deeper into classes, then the parent becomes the current class
            currParentClass = currClass;

            // If you go back out of a class
            currParentClass = currClass.getParent();
        }
    }

    // Traverse the hierarchy
    public void traverse ()
    {
        traverseTree(root);
    }

    private void traverseTree (VMFClass root)
    {
        System.out.println("Class Name: " + root.getName());

        // print out any properties
        VMFProperty prop = root.getProperty();

        if (prop != null)
        {
            System.out.println("Property Name: " + prop.getName());

            String [] props = prop.getValues();
            for (String s: props)
            {
                System.out.println("Value: " + s);
            }
        }

        // get all child classes
        List<VMFClass> children = root.getChildren();
        for (VMFClass c: children)
        {
            traverseTree(c);
        }   
    }
}
```

### Client Code

**Example**

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    VMFParser vmfParser = null;
    try
    {
        vmfParser = new VMFParser("myFile.vmf");
        vmfParser.parse();

        // access the vmfParser for the hierarchy
        vmfParser.traverse();
    }
    catch (VMFParsingException vpe)
    {
        // do something here
        vpe.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        // clean up...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I really appreciate it.  EDIT: now I got it. that seems pretty good

Comment: Using this method all classes seem to be top level classes... You May take a look athttps://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Valve_Map_Format#The_structure_of_.vmf if you haven't already

Comment: I see. I will edit my answer to adapt it to a tree structure.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just looking to find all sub classes of particular class or interface , this might help you,

[How can I get a list of all the implementations of an interface programmatically in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347248/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-the-implementations-of-an-interface-programmatically)

Comment: this would rather be a comment than an answer

Comment: I already have a list of all subclasses... I just need an algorithm to combine them into a "single" object

Comment: Sorry I don't have the privilege to add a comment yet

Comment: so you have all the children combined in a list..., what is the object you are  looking for to 'combine' them?