# Storing all classes that use an interface with reflection?

Tags: java

I know this has been asked before but I am posting this question because I honestly dont know how this would work. The last site I have visited had the following info:

```
Class  aClass = ... //obtain Class object. See prev. section
Class[] interfaces = aClass.getInterfaces();
```

So assuming I had something like this:

```
public interface Speech{
    vocal doomething();
}

class english implements Speech{
    public int doSomething() {
        return 1;
    }

class german implements Speech{
    public int doSomething() {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

How would I store all classes dynamically in an array? Im asking because right now im forced to do the following:

```
static HashMap<String, Speech> map = new HashMap<>();
```

and set the maps manually:

```
 map.put("English", new English());
 map.put("German", new German());
```

But I would like to do something like this:

```
function void setSpeech(String language) {
    map.put(language, new x());
}
```

How is this possible? Can it be done with reflection? If so then how?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/347248/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-the-implementations-of-an-interface-programmatically

Comment: @Fildor is reflection really the right choice?