# how to load types that implements generic interface from java

Tags: java

please note:
this link didn't help
[How can I get a list of all the implementations of an interface programmatically in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347248/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-the-implementations-of-an-interface-programmatically)

Hi I wonder how to load all types in code that Implements a generic interface without using external libraries from java?

for example how to load all types that implemets this interface & create them?

```
public interface MyInterface<TInput> {
Void Foo(TInput input);
}
```

***because this is generic interface I cannot code: MyInterface.class***

can I do something like

```
ServiceLoader<Abc> loader = ServiceLoader.load(Class<? implements MyInterface<Integer>.class);
```

Comment: I have no idea if there is a way to get all implementing classes and interfaces, though I think, you can use java.lang.reflect.Type to compare generic classes.

Comment: But besides all that, you can create a registry for that behavior which might be a lot easier than what you want right now.

Comment: You will almost certainly have to use a library for this, unless you wish to write a fancy class loader. One possible solution is to get a list of all classes using Google's `com.google.common.reflect.ClassPath` class using the `getTopLevelClasses(packageName)` method. Thereafter, you can test each class for implementation of your interface. Even then, this is still a best guess algorithm. It won't guarantee every class will be found.