# How to list all classes implementing a specific interface in Android?

Tags: java, android, reflection

In Java (NetBeans), I realized it with...

```
ClassPathLoader pathLoader = new ClassPathLoader(".");
try {
//get Classes
Hashtable ht = pathLoader.getClasses();
Set s = ht.keySet();
Iterator iter = s.iterator();
String fullName = null;
    while(iter.hasNext()) {
        try {
        fullName = (String) iter.next();
        //create class
        Class cls = Class.forName(fullName);
        //get interface from the class
        Class[] interfaces = cls.getInterfaces();
        for(int i = 0; i < interfaces.length; i++) {
        if(interfaces[i].getName().equals("IMyObserver.IFeature")) {

        //Field field = cls.getDeclaredField("LOCATION");
        //String location = (String)field.get(null);
        Constructor cons2 = cls.getDeclaredConstructor(List.class);

        Object oo = cons2.newInstance(qList);

        System.out.println(fullName);
        }
    }
```

This works very well, but in Android it does not work. I think the problem is at the ClassPath. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Everything is in the same Project file !!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I retrieve all classes that implement a custom interface?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42762240/how-can-i-retrieve-all-classes-that-implement-a-custom-interface)

Comment: When you say _it doesn't work on Android_ you're not saying _what doesn't work_. You get no results? You get an exception? What?