# Java - How to convert a String into specific enum implementing an interface

Tags: java, spring, enums, spring-data-mongodb

Consider below inner `Enum` implementing an interface:

```
public interface NotificationTypes {

    public enum CONTACT_LIST implements NotificationTypes{
        ADDED("CONTACT_LIST-ADDED"),
        REMOVED("CONTACT_LIST-REMOVED");
        public enum INVITATION implements NotificationTypes{
            ACCEPTED("CONTACT_LIST-INVITATION-ACCEPTED"),
            REJECTED("CONTACT_LIST-INVITATION-REJECTED");

            String name = "";
            private INVITATION(String name){
                this.name = name;
            }

            public String getName(){
                return name;
            }
        };

        String name = "";
        private CONTACT_LIST(String name){
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getName(){
            return name;
        }
    }
    public String getName();
}
```

Now consider that data in database/mongodb is stored in the form of `String` for `NotificationTypes` in a table/document.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59882ba49e5d82c72ba44fde"),
    "template" : "Contact list Invitation accepted by your friend",
    "type" : "CONTACT_LIST-INVITATION-ACCEPTED"
}
```

So my question is: ***How to convert that string back into specific enum at runtime without knowing exactly the name of enum to be mapped?***

Domain class is looks like this:

```
@Document(collection = CollectionNames.XXX_TEMPLATE)
public class XXXTemplate {

    private NotificationTypes type;
    //Other parameters, getters & setters + Constructor
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd build a `Map<String, NotificationTypes>` and populate that with all instances you have. You can then look up from that map.

I don't think the compiler can help you a lot with keeping that in sync, other than that you can loop over `EnumType.values()` (but you have to remember to do it for all of your enum types).

Comment: Ok thanks for reply. But in case if I have nested enums upto 3-4 levels, then I have to loop through all enums, isn't?? Is there any short way to loop through all enums implementing given interface(NotificationTypes)?

Comment: No, you have to build that map (statically, spelling out all types in source code). But then the lookup from that map is trivial and fast.

Comment: If you really, really want to have code find all implementations of your interface: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347248/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-the-implementations-of-an-interface-programmatically  But don't. Live with the map or rethink your design.

Answer (score 0):

> How to convert that string back into specific enum at runtime without knowing exactly the name of enum to be mapped?

Via `Enum.valueOf()`.

Comment: But for that you need to know which kind of `enum` it is. And it works with the identifier, not with the custom `name`.

Comment: @EJP thanks for replay. But this method requires enum type as well, and I don't know about that it runtime. There are so many inner enums implementing same interface.

Comment: @Afridi Then you've designed yourself into a corner that isn't supported by the language.

Answer (score 0):

Basically just building on @Thilo's answer, but perhaps a more 'Springified' way if it's something that you'd want - you could define a `@Bean` in your config that contains all your enum values, like:

```
@Configuration
public class Config {
    @Bean
    public List<NotificationTypes> notificationTypes() {
        List<NotificationTypes> notificationTypes = new ArrayList<>();

        notificationTypes.addAll(Arrays.asList(NotificationTypes.CONTACT_LIST.values()));
        notificationTypes.addAll(Arrays.asList(NotificationTypes.CONTACT_LIST.INVITATION.values()));

        return notificationTypes;
    }
}
```

And then `@Autowire` this `@Bean` into a parser to do the actual matching of String to enum, something like:

```
@Component
public class NotificationTypeParser {
    @Autowired
    private List<NotificationTypes> notificationTypes;

    public NotificationTypes parseNotificationType(String type) {
        for (NotificationTypes notificationType : notificationTypes) {
            if (notificationType.getName().equals(type)) {
                return notificationType;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Obviously you probably want something better than just returning `null` if the enum isn't found, and you could potentially do something smarter in the `@Bean` definition to validate that the enums all have different names, etc. Or, conceivably, use reflection in there to find all the implementations of `NotificationTypes`.

I'm not sure that this really gives you any additional benefits over just storing all the possible values in a Map, but, as I say, I suppose it's a bit Spring-ier.