# Strategy - automatically register by interface type

Tags: java, design-patterns, architecture

I have a lot of actions. All actions works with some Object/Context that passed in all actions. I want to use pattern Strategy/Policy.

Here is examples in Kotlin:

```
interface Action {
    val name: String

    fun run(ctx: Context)
}

class Multiply: Action {

    override name = "MULTIPLY"

    override fun run(ctx: Context) {
        writeToDb(ctx.id, ctx.number * 2)
    }
}

class Substract 

class SendNotification

etc...
```

So I want to register all strategies on startup. And select strategy from structure like Enum.

```
val action = selectAwaitingAction()
val ctx = selectCtxById(action.transaction_id)
perfromAction(ctx, actions.getByName(action.name))

fun performAction(ctx Context, action: Action) {
    action.run(ctx)
}
```

My question is how register strategy by interface type?

Comment: Sure it is possible. What is a question? Go ahead and do it.

Comment: @Vadim, I'm stuck on implementing this. I mean how can I register all strategies by Interface

Comment: Code you have posted is not Java. Answers in which language are you looking for?

Comment: @Bedla it's Kotlin. Java or Kotlin, both are good.

Comment: What you are looking for is `java.util.ServiceLoader`.

Comment: @EJP thanks awesome.

Answer (score 0):

*Note: This is complete example. If you are looking only for automatic registration by interface type, scroll to last part of answer.*

**Strategy** design pattern can be implemented using function tables. This stores implementations in `Map<String,IImpl>` where key is name of algorithm and value is concrete implementation of algorithm .

**Common approach:**

Consider class `Context` holding all parameters shared between imlementations of interface `Solver`.

```
public class Context extends HashMap<String,Object> {
public <T> T get(String key, Class<T> resultClass){
    return resultClass.cast(get(key));
}

public <T> T getOrDefault(String key, T def, Class<T> resultClass){
    return resultClass.cast(getOrDefault(key,def));
}
}
```

And interface `Solver` with required methods `solve` and `name`

```
public interface Solver {
void solve(Context context);
String name();
}
```

Then you can create implementations of `Solver` interface modifying shared `Context` object. I have created `AddSolver` and `MultiplySolver` in this example.

AddSolver.java:

```
public class AddSolver implements Solver {

@Override
public void solve(Context context) {
    context.put("result", context.getOrDefault("result",0.0, Double.class) + context.get("add", Double.class));
}

@Override
public String name() {
    return "+";
}
}
```

MultiplySolver.java

```
public class MultiplySolver implements Solver {
@Override
public void solve(Context context) {
    context.put("result", context.getOrDefault("result",0.0, Double.class) * context.get("multiply", Double.class));
}
@Override
public String name() {
    return "*";
}
}
```

---

**Manual construction of `Map<String,Solver>`:**

Implementations of interface `Solver` can be stored in `HashMap<String,Solver>`

```
@Test
public void testCustomFunctionMap(){
    HashMap<String,Solver> functionMap = new HashMap<>();
    functionMap.put("+", new AddSolver());
    functionMap.put("*", new MultiplySolver());

    Context context = new Context();
    context.put("add", 2.0);
    functionMap.get("+").solve(context);
    TestCase.assertEquals(2.0, context.get("result", Double.class));

    context.put("multiply", 3.0);
    functionMap.get("*").solve(context);
    TestCase.assertEquals(6.0, context.get("result", Double.class));
}
```

---

**Automatic construction of `Map<String,Solver>`**

There is more approaches, if you need costruct `Map<String,Solver>` automatically. A lot of them is mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347248/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-the-implementations-of-an-interface-programmatically). I have used [org.reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections) library.

```
public class SolverScanner{
static HashMap<String, Solver> functionMap;
static {
        functionMap = new HashMap<>();
        Reflections reflections = new Reflections(SolverScanner.class.getPackage().getName());
        for( Class<? extends Solver> clazz : reflections.getSubTypesOf(Solver.class)){
            try {
                Solver solver = clazz.newInstance();
                functionMap.put(solver.name(), solver);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot construct functionMap",e);
            }
        }
}
public static HashMap<String, Solver> getFunctionMap(){
    return functionMap;
}
private SolverScanner(){}//disable instantiating
}
```

And usage:

```
@Test
public void testSolverScannerFunctionMap(){
    HashMap<String,Solver> functionMap = SolverScanner.getFunctionMap();

    Context context = new Context();
    context.put("add", 2.0);
    functionMap.get("+").solve(context);
    TestCase.assertEquals(2.0, context.get("result", Double.class));

    context.put("multiply", 3.0);
    functionMap.get("*").solve(context);
    TestCase.assertEquals(6.0, context.get("result", Double.class));
}
```