# Call all Java interface methods

Tags: java, events, interface

In many programs I see that when I implement an interface and override the methods they are called on specific events (example: onActionListener). I need to know how to call the methods from all the class that implements that specific interface. Thanks ahead for the answers.

Comment: make an instance of the implemented class and call the overridden method for each class

Comment: check this out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347248/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-the-implementations-of-an-interface-programmatically

Comment: Would you, by any chance, be trying to ask about how to **fire an event**, i.e., invoke a particular event-handling method in one or more listener class instances?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get a list of all the implementations of an interface programmatically in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347248/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-the-implementations-of-an-interface-programmatically)

Answer (score 1):

You can only call a method of a class if it is `static`. If it is not, you can only call the method of "an Object" (an instance of this class). Now, assume you have a bunch of objects and an interface called ActionListener with `actionPerformed()` method in it. In order to call the method you will have to check if this object `implements ActionListener` - has the `actionPerformed()` method. Then, cast it to action listener, and call the method.

Take a look at this example:

```
JButton b1 = new JButton();
JButton b2 = new JButton();
Object[] objects = { b1, b2 }; // Some objects
for (Object obj : objects) {
    if (obj instanceof ActionListener) { // Check if they implement action listener
        ActionListener objListener = (ActionListener) obj;
        objListener.actionPerformed(new ActionEvent(null, 1, "command"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I know but for example, when you mod a game you override methods provided by the api and the methods are called when they are implemented. I want to achieve this mechanic.