# Is it possible to inject a list of beans implementing an interface using Java EE

Tags: java, dependency-injection, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0

I wonder, if I can inject a list of (stateless) beans, that all implementing a special interface.

For example I've a module contract

```
public interface ResetService {
  void reset(MyContext context);
}
```

Than I've two modules, that are implementing this interface. And one module, that should call all implementations:

```
@EJBs
private List<ResetService> resetServices;

void resetAllModules(MyContext context) {
  for (ResetService resetService : resetServices)
    resetService.reset(context);
}
```

It's important that all calls are in the main transaction and the reset caller must be know, if the reset call is complete. So I can't use JMS and topics.

I think, it's not possible, or?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible with annotations. Your best option here is to loop over an array of JNDI names<sup>1</sup> and to do a JNDI lookup for each to feed your `List`. Just in case, maybe have a look at previous questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/435890/find-java-classes-implementing-an-interface) if you want to try to make things more dynamic (I'm not convinced it would be a good idea).

Answer (score 3):

Privious answer is wrong. You can inject dynamicaly using @Any annotation and javax.enterprise.inject.Instance class. Here simple example http://coders-kitchen.com/2013/01/24/jee-and-dynamic-dependency-injection/

Comment: I think the question was about EJBs. And your blogposts shows the usage of the CDI annotations. The usage and handling on the serverside are totally different between CDI and EJB.

Comment: Previous answer was not wrong 4 years ago. With the latest J2EE spec (version 6) CDI was added which offers a solution.

Comment: The link you posted is dead; here is the archived snapshot: https://web.archive.org/web/20200725142516/http://coders-kitchen.com/2013/01/24/jee-and-dynamic-dependency-injection/

Answer (score 2):

You can get all beans of type by:

```
    @Inject
    BeanManager beanManager;

    public Set<ResetService> getAllResetServices() {
       return beanManager.getBeans(ResetService.class);
    }
```

Comment: BeanManager.getBeans returns Set<Bean<?>> so it's not a solution. More info here https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/inject/spi/BeanManager.html