# Java- How do I gather classes by using enum?

Tags: java

Let's assume that I have lots of implementations of matrices (Which don't extend from one to another) and I want the user to be able to see all the different classes, to gather them in some kind of enum or something, How can I do that?
It doesn't have to be a menu or something, just so I will be able to see all the classes, just like enum.

For example:

```
MainMatrix matrix= new (ALL THE POSSIBILITIES)();
```

While the MainMatrix is the common interface of all matrices.

Can I use enum that will create instance of new class matching the option I'll choose? 
for example:

```
public enum Matrices{
DIAGONAL_MATRIX(new DiagonalMatrix());
..
..
}
```

Can I do that?

Comment: Check out this SO question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/435890/find-java-classes-implementing-an-interface

Comment: also check out this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3123095/how-can-i-find-all-implementations-of-interface-in-classpath

Comment: Thanks for the questions, I don't find them useful for what I'm asking. I'm offering a specific idea and wonder if it's correct..

Comment: So you want to find all implementations of MainMatrix and create an enum of them?

Comment: I know all the implementations of MainMatrix, I wonder if I can use enum to create the instance that I want?

Comment: I posted answer for what I think I should do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here a solution using an enum with an abstract method:

```
public enum MatrixFactory {

    /**
     * Creates a diagonal matrix
     * 
     * args[0] : a double[] with the diagonal values
     */
    DIAGONAL_MATRIX {
        @Override
        public MainMatrix create(Object[] args) {
            double[] diagonal = (double[]) args[0];
            return new DiagonalMatrix(diagonal);
        }
    },

    /**
     * Creates a full matrix
     * 
     * args[0] : the number of rows
     * 
     * args[1] : the number of columns
     */
    FULL_MATRIX() {
        @Override
        public MainMatrix create(Object[] args) {
            int rows = (Integer) args[0];
            int cols = (Integer) args[1];
            return new FullMatrix(rows, cols);
        }
    };

    public abstract MainMatrix create(Object[] args);
}
```

Usage:

```
MatrixFactory.DIAGONAL_MATRIX.create(new Object[] {new double[] {1.0, 2.0, 3.0}});
MatrixFactory.FULL_MATRIX.create(new Object[] {4, 4});
```

See also the [classic enum tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/language/enums.html) which illustrates this with an arithmetic enum:

```
public enum Operation {
  PLUS   { double eval(double x, double y) { return x + y; } },
  MINUS  { double eval(double x, double y) { return x - y; } },
  TIMES  { double eval(double x, double y) { return x * y; } },
  DIVIDE { double eval(double x, double y) { return x / y; } };

  // Do arithmetic op represented by this constant
  abstract double eval(double x, double y);
}
```

I advocate a regular factory though, because the usage is much clearer. Using an enum does not add any benefits I can think of in this context.

```
public class MatrixFactory {

    /**
     * Creates a diagonal matrix
     * 
     * @param diagonal the diagonal values
     * @return
     */
    public static MainMatrix diagonalMatrix(double[] diagonal) {
        return new DiagonalMatrix(diagonal);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a full matrix
     * 
     * @param rows the number of rows
     * @param cols the number of columns
     * @return
     */
    public static MainMatrix fullMatrix(int rows, int cols) {
        return new FullMatrix(rows, cols);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
MatrixFactory.diagonalMatrix(new double[] {1.0, 2.0, 3.0});
MatrixFactory.fullMatrix(4, 4);
```

Comment: A nicer and more complete answer than mine if I do say so myself :-) Nice one Adriaan!

Answer (score 4):

You can do this programmatically with the [Reflections](http://code.google.com/p/reflections/) library.

For example:

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections(...); //see in other use cases
Set<Class<? extends MainMatrix>> subTypes =
    reflections.getSubTypesOf(MainMatrix.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to have a method in your enum to create the matrix (mostly based on what you already wrote):

```
public enum Matrices{
    DIAGONAL_MATRIX {
        @Override
        public MainMatrix createMatrix() {
            return new DiagonalMatrix();
        }
    },
    OTHER_MATRIX {
        @Override
        public MainMatrix createMatrix() {
            return new OtherMatrix();
        }
    },
    ...
    ;

    public abstract MainMatrix createMatrix();
}
```

---

EDIT:
just call the `createMatrix` method to create a matrix for a given enum:

```
Matrices type = ...
MainMatrix matrix = type.createMatrix();
```

or directly

```
MainMatrix matrix = DIAGONAL_MATRIX.createMatrix();
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, how can we make an instance of DIAGONAL_MATRIX after using this enum?
MainMatrix matrix= Matrices.DIAGONAL_MATRIX; ?
Will it be o.k? I think that I'll have a compilation error, no?

Comment: @Nir - added it to my answer above

Answer (score 1):

We can create some kind of **Matrix Factory**:

```
public class MatrixImplFactory {
     IMatrixImpl createMatrix(double[] diagonal) {
          return new DiagonalMatrix(diagonal);
           }
     IMatrixImpl createMatrix(int rows, int cols) {
          return new FullMatrix(rows, cols);
           }
    }
```

I just need to make sure that each matrix will have different type of constructor.

Making instance of a matrix in this way:

```
public class Matrix implements IMatrix {
       protected IMatrixImpl impl;
       MatrixFacotry factory;
   public Matrix(int rows, int cols) {
          impl = factory.createMatrix(rows, cols);
          }
         ....

         }
```

Comment: +1 You just beat me to it! (-: I suggest making all the factory methods static and removing the field 'MatrixFacotry factory'. Then you can simply create a matrix by MatrixImplFactory.createMatrix(...). A reason to make a factory non static and implementing an interface would be if you want to allow for multiple different factory implementations (classes of factories) which is called the 'Abstract factory' pattern (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern).

Comment: Thanks! :-) Still I don't choose the name of the matrix, like I wanted. I wonder if this enum idea can be executed.
Thanks for the idea, it's much better than create an instance of the MatrixImplFactory.

Comment: Sure you could make an enum version of this. I will post an answer in a couple of minutes to demonstrate. However, you will need to standardize the arguments of the factory methods (like an Object[] args) which doesn't improve the usability of the API. A normal factory is the way to go I think. If you want you can represent the name of the matrix in the method name.

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be what you want to try:

```
public enum Matricies {

    DIAGONAL_MATRIX(new DiagonalMatrix()),
    OTHER_MATRIX(new OtherMatrix(4, 4));

    private MainMatrix value; // each value of the enum has a value which is an instance of a matrix

    Matricies(MainMatrix val) { // enum constructor to set instance of matrix
        value = val;
    }

    public MainMatrix getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

To get instance of diagonal matrix:

```
MainMatrix diagMatrix = Matricies.DIAGONAL_MATRIX.getValue();
```

Comment: Jeez, I keep getting beaten to it! However, this solution does not allow the client to pass any creation arguments...

Comment: What if we were to add a setter? So we can set that value that DIAGONAL_MATRIX has...

Comment: See the answer I just posted. You can give an enum an abstract method.

Answer (score 0):

1. Write the above code in Eclipse
2. Put the cursor within the text `MainMatrix`
3. Press `F4`.

`F4` is the Eclipse shortcut to open the 'Type Hierarchy' view. This will show you all sub-types of the currently selected type.

Comment: Thank you but I want to write a code for that, a common class or something, I don't mind the technical side.

Answer (score 0):

If all the classes are implementations of matrices, then it probably makes sense to have them implement a common interface, or extend a common abstract class. With this simple 2 level hierarchy, you can also build an array of the common super-class/interface. Here's an example of what I mean:

```
public class AA {

    public interface MainMatrix {

    }

    public class MatrixA implements MainMatrix {

    }

    public class MatrixB implements MainMatrix {

    }

    public void go() {
        MainMatrix[] mainMatrices = new MainMatrix[2];
        mainMatrices[0] = new MatrixA();
        mainMatrices[1] = new MatrixB();
    }

}
```

Comment: In the question Nir states that all Matrix classes implement MainMatrix. "with this simple 2 level hierarchy you can also build an array of the common super-class" - this is the question, how do you do this?

Comment: I added a code snippet showing what I meant. I think the question was slightly modified after I posted my answer, and I probably misunderstood the original question.