# How can I get all implementations of an interface at runtime in Kotlin

Tags: reflection, kotlin

I know I can get all subclasses of a `sealed class` in Kotlin, but I'm looking for a way to get all implementations of an interface.

So instead of ...

```
sealed class HotDrinkFactory {
    abstract fun prepare(amount: Int): HotDrink
}

class TeaFactory : HotDrinkFactory() {
    override fun prepare(amount: Int): HotDrink {
        ...
    }
}

class CoffeeFactory : HotDrinkFactory() {
    override fun prepare(amount: Int): HotDrink {
        ...
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val hotDrinkFactories = HotDrinkFactory::class.sealedSubclasses
    hotDrinkFactories.forEach { println(it::class.qualifiedName) }
}
```

... I would like to have

```
interface HotDrinkFactory {
    fun prepare(amount: Int): HotDrink
}

class TeaFactory : HotDrinkFactory {
    override fun prepare(amount: Int): HotDrink {
        ...
    }
}

class CoffeeFactory : HotDrinkFactory {
    override fun prepare(amount: Int): HotDrink {
        ...
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val hotDrinkFactories = HotDrinkFactory::class.<<< Something here? >>>
    hotDrinkFactories.forEach { println(it::class.qualifiedName) }
}
```

Comment: [This is not _really_ possible without some workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3123134/7366707); maybe rethinking the design would be a better idea.

Comment: @Moira Yeah, I already found that post, but I hoped there would be a way by now with Kotlin.

Comment: What problem do you want to solve with that code? Sounds like a Service Provider Interface (SPI) could serve you well. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/SPI-intro.html

Comment: @Simulant I'm building a console application, where I would like to get the class names and output them as options to the user. To be fair, this is just a practice project