# Program to find classes implementing an Interface in Java using eclipse IDE

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find Java classes implementing an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/435890/find-java-classes-implementing-an-interface)

Hi. I have been trying to find out a way to write a program that is able to find all classes that are implementing a particular interface. One way would be to iterate over the classpath i think, but is there a better way to do this, maybe using any built in eclipse functionalities?

Comment: dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/435890/find-java-classes-implementing-an-interface

Answer (score 0):

There's some thoughts in [this thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/435890/find-java-classes-implementing-an-interface).  As far as Eclipse, it is open source.  You could download the source code and look how they do it.  (open type hierarchy is the function in the GUI)

Comment: Or get IntelliJ - it tells you all the classes that implement an interface at the touch of an icon.