# How to get all classes which implement specified interface

Tags: java, android, reflection, classloader

How to get all classes which implement specified interface in Android?
I think Classloader and Class classes should be used somehow..

Walking all loaded by classloader classes and checking, if it implements specified interface, is not good idea i suppose.

I've found similar question and perfect answers here: [Find Java classes implementing an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/435890/find-java-classes-implementing-an-interface).

BUT Dalvik has some restrictions and i wonder which method is available on Android.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Google reflections](http://code.google.com/p/reflections/) library. This would build and search an index of reverse reflection data (i.e. find subclasses instead of find super classes) and should provide what you want.

Comment: Does not work( Can not be compiled: http://code.google.com/p/reflections/issues/detail?id=98&thanks=98&ts=1327489720