# Injecting into a list with Guice (or Spring)

Tags: dependencies, guice, code-injection

I have a list of actions implementing the Action interface.

```
FooAction implements Action
BarAction implements Action
```

I want to be able to process each action in a List :-

```
List<Action> actions = new ArrayList<Action>;
..

for( Action action : actions)
    action.process();
```

Is it possible to get Guice (or spring !) to inject all the individual Actions into the actions list ? 
I know I can write code to manually create a set like this :-

```
Multibinder<Action> actionBinder = Multibinder.newSetBinder(binder(), Action.class);

actionBinder.addBinding().to( FooAction.class );
actionBinder.addBinding().to( BarAction.class );
```

But it would be nice if I could write new action classes that are picked up automatically and injected into my list? 
or is this just wishful thinking.

Answer (score 2):

As mlk eluded to, you're looking for a classpath scanner.  We use reflections:

http://code.google.com/p/reflections/

You will probably want to look at their "getSubTypesOf" method.  We use that, as well as their "getTypesAnnotatedWith" method extensively to find all classes of a certain flavor at startup so they can be bound to lists at startup.

Answer (score 1):

Java does not know of all the available implementations. You would have to loop over all the classes in the class path and inspect them (see [Find Java classes implementing an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/435890/find-java-classes-implementing-an-interface)), the other option would be to inform Guice or Spring via configuration files in known locations (this is how plugins often work).

Comment: I know java dosnt know about this but is there a Guice or Spring annotation that causes the Guice binder to be populated for me (after all it could do it, if it wasnt a list) at run time, rather than me hard coding it by calling 'addBinding()' ?

Comment: No annotation exists in Guice. You would have to write it yourself. As stated above, Java does not know so you would have to scan the class path.