# List the classes / interfaces that a Clojure protocol has been extended to

Tags: java, clojure, protocols

Suppose I have a Clojure protocol:

```
(defprotocol Foo
  (bar [x]))
```

I know this protocol may have been extended (with `extend-protocol` or `extend-type`) to a number of Java classes and/or interfaces.

How can I obtain a list of the classes that `Foo` has been extended to at runtime?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14246945/clojure-listing-all-deftypes-that-implement-some-protocol-within-the-namespace?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

Protocols are implemented as map data structure as the example shows:

```clj
user=> (defprotocol Foo (bar [x]))
Foo
user=> Foo
{:on-interface user.Foo, :on user.Foo, :sigs {:bar {:doc nil, :arglists ([x]), :name bar}}, :var #'user/Foo, :method-map {:bar :bar}, :method-builders {#'user/bar #<user$eval331$fn__332 user$eval331$fn__332@cdd54e>}}
user=> (extend-protocol Foo String (bar [x] x))
nil
user=> Foo
{:impls {java.lang.String {:bar #<user$eval350$fn__351 user$eval350$fn__351@25bd56>}}, :on-interface user.Foo, :on user.Foo, :sigs {:bar {:doc nil, :arglists ([x]), :name bar}}, :var #'user/Foo, :method-map {:bar :bar}, :method-builders {#'user/bar #<user$eval331$fn__332 user$eval331$fn__332@cdd54e>}}
```

So, to get the implementations of a protocol you can use:
`(Foo :impls)`

Comment: This appears to be precisely how the `extenders` funcion is implemented (except `extenders` returns just the keys — i.e., just the classes).  Given that the representation of protocols may change over time, it's probably best to use `extenders` if you only need the types.

Answer (score 2):

cf. [`extenders`](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/extenders) and SO wants me to type more characters.

Answer (score -1):

There are two cases to deal with

- `extend-type` and `extend-protocol`
- `deftype` and `defrecord`

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/14261880/1756702 for an answer discussing this.

Comment: This is a word-for-word copy of my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14246945/clojure-listing-all-deftypes-that-implement-some-protocol-within-the-namespace?rq=1. Please do not represent my work as your own -- if you would like to use my answer in helping to answer this question, then you should summarize and provide a link to the original.

Comment: I have flagged and edited this to address the plagiarism. Feel free to improve the summary, but make sure you give credit to the original author.