# How to figure out what protocols the type implements?

Tags: reflection, clojure, clojurescript

Given some type or record, how can I get all the protocols it implements?

Let's say we have the following code:

```
(defprotocol P1
  (op1 [this]))

(defprotocol P2
  (op2 [this]))

(defrecord R []
  P1
  (op1 [_] 1)
  P2
  (op2 [_] 2))
```

And what I need is a function that does something like this:

```
(all-protocols-for-type R) ;; => (P1 P2)
```

It will be good if there's something backend-agnosting, because I'd like to have a mechanism for both Clojure and ClojureScript.

UPD: the intention for this is to introspect what functionality the particular type provides. Let's say, by doing this:

```
user> (supers (type {}))
#{clojure.lang.AFn clojure.lang.ILookup java.lang.Object java.util.Map clojure.lang.Seqable java.lang.Runnable clojure.lang.IPersistentCollection java.io.Serializable clojure.lang.IFn clojure.lang.APersistentMap clojure.lang.Associative java.util.concurrent.Callable clojure.lang.IKVReduce clojure.lang.Counted clojure.lang.IMeta clojure.lang.IMapIterable java.lang.Iterable clojure.lang.IPersistentMap clojure.lang.IEditableCollection clojure.lang.IObj clojure.lang.MapEquivalence clojure.lang.IHashEq}
```

I will know that I can use map as a function (`IFn`), lookup a value by key there (`Associative`) and even do `reduce-kv` on it (`IKVReduce`).

Comment: You could also use `(hara.class.inheritance/ancestor-tree R)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the closest you can get in Clojure without doing something crazy:

```
(require '[clojure.set :as set])

(deftype EmptyType [])

(defrecord EmptyRecord [])

(defn all-protocols-for-type [t]
  (map (comp symbol (memfn getSimpleName))
       (set/difference (supers t)
                       (set/union (supers EmptyType)
                                  (supers EmptyRecord)))))
```

I used that specific `map` just to get an output with the same format you gave in your question; you should modify the mapping function as you see fit.

Basically, what you're asking is the other side of the coin to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14246945/clojure-listing-all-deftypes-that-implement-some-protocol-within-the-namespace). Extension of a protocol using `deftype` or `defrecord` stores the information on the type, and extension using `extend-type` or `extend-protocol` stores the information on the protocol.

So if all your extensions are done directly in `deftype` or `defrecord`, you can get all the protocols for a given type using the method I gave above. If all your extensions are done with `extend-type` or `extend-protocol`, you can get all the types for a given protocol using the method Alex gave in his answer to that other question. But there isn't a nice way to do both in all cases.

Comment: `supers` would return interfaces too, it's worth mentioning that since the question is for querying protocols only. I like this answer otherwise. Curious; how does one distinguish an interface from a protocol?

Comment: @muhuk Good point! I was thinking about that when I wrote the function, but I had forgotten by the time I wrote the answer. As Alex pointed out in [his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14246945/clojure-listing-all-deftypes-that-implement-some-protocol-within-the-namespace), the difference between an interface and a protocol is that a protocol stores a map of extra data in addition to the interface itself. I suppose you could take the `Class`es returned by `difference`, do some name-mangling on them, and use that to look for protocols, but I'm not sure if there's a better option.

Comment: Great! Actually I'm completely OK with the only usage of `supers`. Didn't know that it exists.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible in general, on the JVM at least, since extending a type to a protocol leaves no information on the type, only on the protocol. In clojurescript I'm not sure. Why do you want this? It's not really very useful to have a list of protocols, if you don't even know what those protocols are for.

Answer (score 0):

> And what I need is a function that does something like this:
>
> ```
> (all-protocols-for-type R) ;; => (P1 P2)
> ```

I can't possibly think of any real world utility of **a list of protocols implemented for a type**, unless this list will be compared to another list of protocol references.

If the protocol references (in the 2nd list) is known the following would do:

```
(defn extends-all? [protocols typ]
  (reduce (fn [acc p] (and acc (extends? p typ)))
          true
          protocols))
(extends-all? [P1 P2] R) ;; => true
```

If the goal isn't to compare against a list of protocols, please update the question with the actual use case.