# How to wrap Exception in Clojure Macro?

Tags: clojure, functional-programming, macros, lisp

I would like to wrap exception which has been thrown by system or user(does not matter) and force it to return some value.

I wrote macro for it but it does not work.

Macro:

```
(defmacro safe-fn
  [form]
  (try
    `(do ~form)
    (catch Throwable e
      1)))
```

Usage: `(safe-fn (throw (RuntimeException. "Try me!")))`

Actual output: `RuntimeException Try me!  clojure-brave-and-true.core/eval2219 (form-init6122238559239237921.clj:1)`

Desired output: `1`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Macros are just functions that return code to be evaluated, so you could write `safe-fn` like this:

```clj
(defmacro safe-fn
  [form]
  `(try
     ~form
     (catch Throwable ~'_
       1)))
```

Example:

```clj
(safe-fn (throw (RuntimeException. "Try me!")))
;=> 1
```

See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35977973/5044950) for more detail on macros, and specifically on using them to catch exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

The macro `with-exception-default` from [the Tupelo library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo#default-value-in-case-of-exception) does exactly what you want:

> Default Value in Case of Exception
>
> Sometimes you know an operation may result in an Exception, and you
>   would like to have the Exception converted into a default value. That
>   is when you need:

```
(with-exception-default default-val & body)
  Evaluates body & returns its result.  In the event of an exception the
  specified default value is returned instead of the exception."

(with-exception-default 0
  (Long/parseLong "12xy3"))
;=> 0
```

> This feature is put to good use in tupelo.parse, where you will find
>   functions that work like this:

```
(parse-long "123")                  ; throws if parse error
;=> 123
(parse-long "1xy23" :default 666)   ; returns default val if parse error
;=> 666
```