# Scala - scan package/folder for implementations of a Trait

Tags: java, scala, reflection

If wonder if it's possible to "scan" for classes that implement a certain trait and are located in a pred-defined package and/or folder. My application provides a trait that can be implemented, it would be nice to programmatically get a list of all implementations at runtime without having to "manually register" every implementation first.

I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17490779/scala-reflection-loading-or-finding-classes-based-on-trait) and the accepted answer proposes the usage of `ServiceLoader`. However, it's still necessary to list the available implementations in a text file (`META-INF/services`).

I understand that it probably would be too expensive to scan all classes for the specific type. But I thought that perhaps restricting the search to a certain package or folder could help?

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/nyavro/spi-plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections) or [`org.clapper.util.classutil.ClassFinder`](http://software.clapper.org/javautil/) libraries, since "classes that implement a trait" are compiled to classes which implement the corresponding interface. See also [Is it possible to get all classes that implementing an interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15307814/is-it-possible-to-get-all-classes-that-implementing-an-interface) and the linked questions.