# Search maven central for classes extending a given class

Tags: java, maven, maven-central

How can I search the whole Maven Central repository for classes extending a given class?

(The concrete reason I ask this is that I’d like to see examples of extensions of [FileSystemProvider](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/spi/FileSystemProvider.html), but I am interested in the question more generally.)

I am also interested in searching for all classes implementing a given interface, I guess the procedure will be similar.

(Here is a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34462891) about searching for classes in the class path; but this question is about searching in the whole Maven Central repository.)

Comment: I think the answer is that there is no practical way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know any option of searching in Maven Central repository, but here's another alternative that might help you.

You could use the GitHub search feature, and what I did was to search for keywords `"extends FileSystemProvider"`. Also, you have the option to select the language, Java in this case. Here's the link to that query: https://github.com/search?q=%22extends+FileSystemProvider%22+language%3AJava&type=Code

For implementing a specific interface, you would search for `"implements InterfaceToSearchFor"`

This way, you may find some examples of class extensions/interface implementations.