# Inheritance object creation using spring

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, autowired

Is there a better way to create objects using **`spring autowiring`** or any other `design patterns`?

I have **100** different types of events, I am trying to avoid repeating `case` statement 100 times.

Comment: In order not to write if or case statements, you should build a polymorphic structure. Create an interface and implement it with your events. Then you can have all the objects that implements that interface with java reflection.  check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/435890/find-java-classes-implementing-an-interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare an ApplicationContext:

```
@Autowired 
ApplicationContext context;
```

Then do an:

```
EventBean event = (EventBean) context.getBean(eventType);
```

You will have to name the event beans so the type matches their name.

Comment: can you explain? how does context.getBean check the condition eventType and create appropriate object ? constants are defined with three character values; cancel = cxe, create = cre etc

Comment: Your beans have one or many names, by default the name of the method you used to create them, or the name of the class. `getBean()` looks for a bean which matches the name you pass in parameter. So, if your constant `CANCEL_EVENT` matches `CancelEventBean`, it will return that type of event.

Comment: they won't match. they are different and I can't control constant values.

Comment: You have to make it match somehow. Either rename or add a name to the beans themselves, or create your own constants. You can't expect Spring to guess which bean without at least a clue.