# Enum-aware ServiceLoader implementation?

Tags: java, enums, serviceloader

I would like to be able to indicate an enum type as an interface implementation and then load all enums as separate instances/implementations of the interface via the `ServiceLoader` API. An example of this use case would be to allow downstream users of my API to specify custom values, but provide an enum with standard/common implementations.  My interface only requires a String `name()`, so any enum implements it already.

For example, the `CopyOption` interface in the Java NIO APIs, with the provided `StandardCopyOption` enum. Say I wanted to load all `CopyOption`s, even new ones on the classpath along with the standards, to a single iterator via `ServiceLoader` (or I'm open to other suggestions!)

I finally got it to work by wholesale copying `ServiceLoader` and modifying it to try using `getEnumConstants` when instantiation fails (the part in the `try` is how it works currently and the part in the `catch` is what I added/changed):

```java
try {
    S p = service.cast(c.newInstance());
    providers.put(cn, p);
    return p;
} catch (Throwable x) {
    Object[] arr = c.getEnumConstants();
    if (arr == null || arr.length == 0) {
        fail(service, "Provider " + cn + " could not be instantiated", x);  
    }

    List<S> list = new LinkedList<>();
    for (Object o : arr) {
        Enum<?> e = (Enum<?>) o;
        S p = service.cast(e);
        providers.put(cn + e.ordinal(), p);
        list.add(p);
    }
    subiter = list.iterator();
    return subiter.next();
}
```

I also added some code such that if `subiter` exists and has next, it is iterated before moving on to the next class name.

**My question is: Is there a better way?**

In case the end use is not clear, this is now what's possible with the above modifications:

```java
interface ImageType {
    String name();
}

@AutoService(ImageType.class)
enum StandardImageType implements ImageType {
    IMAGE,
    VECTOR,
    RASTER,
    HANDWRITING,
    ICON,
    LOGO,
    SEAL,
    RULE,
    BARCODE
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the introduction of Java modules, [an alternative](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.7.4) to instantiating via default constructor has been added to service providers. But it only work when the provider is in a named module.

The provider class may declare a `public static T provider()` method where `T` is the service type. Then, the provider implementation class doesn’t even need to implement or extend `T` itself.

Since neither, arrays nor a generic type like `List<ImageType>` can be used as service type, we would need another type for potentially encapsulating multiple actual instances, e.g.

```
package somemodule;

import java.util.function.Supplier;

public interface ImageType {
    String name();
    interface ImageTypes extends Supplier<ImageType[]> {}
}
```

and

```
package somemodule;

public enum StandardImageType implements ImageType {
    IMAGE,
    VECTOR,
    RASTER,
    HANDWRITING,
    ICON,
    LOGO,
    SEAL,
    RULE,
    BARCODE;

    public static ImageTypes provider() {
        return StandardImageType::values;
    }
}
```

and a module declaration like

```
module SomeModule {
    uses somemodule.ImageType.ImageTypes;
    provides somemodule.ImageType.ImageTypes with somemodule.StandardImageType;
}
```

which allows to write, e.g.

```
List<ImageType> all = ServiceLoader.load(ImageType.ImageTypes.class)
        .stream().flatMap(p -> Arrays.stream(p.get().get()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

somewhere within the module (or any other module with a `uses somemodule.ImageType.ImageTypes;` declaration).

Comment: Wow! great news- thank you! and to confirm: this will still pick up/iterate through "normal" implementations e.g.

@AutoService(ImageType.class)
class MyCustomImageType implements ImageType { ...

in addition to the ones provided via an explicit provider?

Comment: This depends on the framework which implements the `@AutoService` feature. As said, the new feature only works with declared modules, so the framework must generate `provides` declarations (or inject their compiled equivalent) to the module-info. Writing the class name to a file in `META-INF/services` won't work with modules.

Comment: That last sentence answered my question thank you. I was referring to Google's `@AutoService` annotation as a convenience for maintaining `META-INF/services` but that's what my question was getting at

Comment: Shouldn't `StandardImageType` also implement `ImageTypes` interface, or is that no longer a requirement? Intellij seems to complain about it even when using provider static method.

Comment: @Dragas it works in Netbeans and [the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.7.4) says explicitly: “*Also, note that when a service provider declares a provider method, the service provider itself need not be a subtype of the service.*”

Comment: Right. It was actually my error, since provider method was only added at java 9, while im still on 8.

Comment: @Dragas I hinted at it in my answer when I wrote "*But it only work when the provider is in a named module*"...