# How to walk through Java class resources?

Tags: java, resources, classpath

I know we can do something like this:

```
Class.class.getResourceAsStream("/com/youcompany/yourapp/module/someresource.conf")
```

to read the files that are packaged within our jar file.

I have googled it a lot and I am surely not using the proper terms; what I want to do is to list the available resources, something like this:

```
Class.class.listResources("/com/yourcompany/yourapp")
```

That should return a list of resources that are inside the package `com.yourcompany.yourapp.*`

Is that possible? Any ideas on how to do it in case it can't be done as easily as I showed?

Note: I know it is possible to know where your jar is and then open it and inspect its contents to achieve it. But, I can't do it in the environment I am working in now.

Comment: Is something like ServiceLoader an option? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/251336 That is, instead of listing a "directory" on the classpath at runtime, you provide a list of resources explicitly at compile time, and store it on the classpath in a well-known location.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For resources in a JAR file, something like this works:

```
URL url = MyClass.class.getResource("MyClass.class");
String scheme = url.getProtocol();
if (!"jar".equals(scheme))
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported scheme: " + scheme);
JarURLConnection con = (JarURLConnection) url.openConnection();
JarFile archive = con.getJarFile();
/* Search for the entries you care about. */
Enumeration<JarEntry> entries = archive.entries();
while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
  JarEntry entry = entries.nextElement();
  if (entry.getName().startsWith("com/y/app/")) {
    ...
  }
}
```

You can do the same thing with resources "exploded" on the file system, or in many other repositories, but it's not quite as easy. You need specific code for each URL scheme you want to support.

Comment: Thank for the example,
Does it use the classloader to reach the resources ?
Or it acts like a helper for opening the jar file and inspect its contentes manually ?

Comment: It is a mix of both. It uses the class loader to locate the resource. Then you have to manually list the contents. I didn't show this, but once you have the list of contents, you can return to the class loader for loading if you desire, or load them directly from the archive yourself.

Comment: Hmm, Supose you are in the appengine java vm implementation. It wont allow you to open the file. That was more or less the point. So I think this is the rigth answer, but what I wanted to do is not possible. It may have security concerns implications to not allow it :(

Thanks erickson

Comment: Are these jar files you're building yourself? If so, add an extra file (with a fixed name) which contains a list of the other files.

Comment: Note, JarURLConnection.getJarFile may (and often should) return null. It makes much more sense to do something along the lines of what Jon Skeet says.

Comment: @Jon Skeet
That is exactly what I didn't want to do but it seems that is the only way to achieve it, and is confirmed now :(
Thanks !

Comment: @Jon Skeet & tackline: I suggested using ServiceLoader as an alternative in a comment (I put on the question itself) yesterday, but it isn't what the question is asking.

Answer (score 4):

In general can't get a list of resources like this. Some classloaders may not even be *able* to support this - imagine a classloader which can fetch individual files from a web server, but the web server doesn't have to support listing the contents of a directory. 
For a jar file you can load the contents of the jar file explicitly, of course.

([This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676097/java-resource-as-file) is similar, btw.)

Comment: It will be nice to understand why the classloaders don't allow it or why the jre does not provide an easy way to do it :(

Comment: @David: I gave an example of why it's not always feasible - the situation where the only access you have in the underlying store (the web) is "fetch this file".

Comment: I am sorry, now I got it. It was my bad english and probably lack of attention. Now I understand you. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The most robust mechanism for listing all resources in the classpath is currently [to use this pattern with ClassGraph](https://github.com/classgraph/classgraph/wiki/Code-examples#finding-and-reading-resource-files), because it handles the [widest possible array of classpath specification mechanisms](https://github.com/classgraph/classgraph/wiki/Classpath-Specification-Mechanisms), including the new JPMS module system. (I am the author of ClassGraph.)

```
List<String> resourceNames;
try (ScanResult scanResult = new ClassGraph()
            .whitelistPaths("com/yourcompany/yourapp")
            .scan()) {
    resourceNames = scanResult.getAllResources().getNames();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've been looking for a way to list the contents of a jar file using the classloaders, but unfortunately this seems to be impossible. Instead what you can do is open the jar as a zip file and get the contents this way. You can use standard ([here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/File-Input-Output/ReadingtheContentsofaZIPFile.htm)) ways to read the contents of a jar file and then use the classloader to read the contents.

Answer (score -1):

I usually use

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(...)
```

but I doubt you can list the entries from the classpath, without knowing them a priori.

Comment: Can you show please a reference that points what you are saying as a fact ?