# Getting list of fully qualified names from a simple name

Tags: java, reflection, classloader

I would like to get a list of classes that are available at runtime and that match a simple name.

For example:

```
public List<String> getFQNs(String simpleName) {
    ...
}

// Would return ["java.awt.List","java.util.List"]
List<String> fqns = getFQNs("List")
```

Is there a library that would do this efficiently, or do I have to manually go through all classes in each classloader? What would be the correct way of doing that?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

One responder asked me why I wanted to do this. Essentially, I want to implement a feature that is similar to "organize imports/auto import", but available at runtime. I don't mind if the solution is relatively slow (especially if I can then build a cache so subsequent queries become faster) and **if it is a best-effort** only. For example, I don't mind if I do not get dynamically generated classes.

**UPDATE 2**

I had to devise my own solution (see below): it uses some hints provided by the other responders, but I came to realize that it needs to be extensible to handle various environments. It is not possible to automatically traverse all classloaders at runtime so you have to rely on general and domain-specific strategies to get a useful list of classes.

Comment: I'm not even sure that you can list loaded classes from a class loader. This might help you http://media.techtarget.com/tss/static/articles/content/dm_loadedClasses/executing.pdf

Comment: @Colin: Even then, this would let you find classes that have already been loaded by a class loader, but not classes that are "available at runtime". AFAIK there's no way to know whether a given class is available without attempting to load it.

Comment: @Grodriguez: You are right that there is no way to know. Consider class loaders that generate bytecode on-the-fly at runtime.

Comment: @Adam and @Grodriguez, thanks for your comment. I made my question more precise: I don't mind if it is a best-effort only and if I miss some classes (e.g., dynamically generated classes).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I mixed the the answers from @Grodriguez and @bemace and added my own strategy to come up with a best-effort solution. This solution imitates at runtime the auto-import feature available at compile time.

The full code of [my solution is here](https://web.archive.org/web/20101128223748/http://helloworld.infobart.com/index.php/recipes/java-getting-fqns-from-a-simplename/). Given a simple name, the main steps are:

1. Get a list of packages accessible from the current classloader.
2. For each package, try to load the fully qualified name obtained from package + simple name.

Step 2 is easy:

```
public List<String> getFQNs(String simpleName) {
    if (this.packages == null) {
        this.packages = getPackages();
    }

    List<String> fqns = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String aPackage : packages) {
        try {
            String fqn = aPackage + "." + simpleName;
            Class.forName(fqn);
            fqns.add(fqn);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Ignore
        }
    }
    return fqns;
}
```

Step 1 is harder and is dependent on your application/environment so I implemented various strategies to get different lists of packages.

**Current Classloader** (may be useful to detect dynamically generated classes)

```
public Collection<String> getPackages() {
    Set<String> packages = new HashSet<String>();
    for (Package aPackage : Package.getPackages()) {
        packages.add(aPackage.getName());
    }
    return packages;
}
```

**Classpath** (good enough for applications that are entirely loaded from the classpath. Not good for complex applications like Eclipse)

```
public Collection<String> getPackages() {
    String classpath = System.getProperty("java.class.path");
    return getPackageFromClassPath(classpath);
}

public static Set<String> getPackageFromClassPath(String classpath) {
    Set<String> packages = new HashSet<String>();
    String[] paths = classpath.split(File.pathSeparator);
    for (String path : paths) {
        if (path.trim().length() == 0) {
            continue;
        } else {
            File file = new File(path);
            if (file.exists()) {
                String childPath = file.getAbsolutePath();
                if (childPath.endsWith(".jar")) {
                    packages.addAll(ClasspathPackageProvider
                            .readZipFile(childPath));
                } else {
                    packages.addAll(ClasspathPackageProvider
                            .readDirectory(childPath));
                }
            }
        }

    }
    return packages;
}
```

**Bootstrap classpath** (e.g., java.lang)

```
public Collection<String> getPackages() {
    // Even IBM JDKs seem to use this property...
    String classpath = System.getProperty("sun.boot.class.path");
    return ClasspathPackageProvider.getPackageFromClassPath(classpath);
}
```

**Eclipse bundles** (domain-specific package provider)

```
// Don't forget to add "Eclipse-BuddyPolicy: global" to MANIFEST.MF
public Collection<String> getPackages() {
    Set<String> packages = new HashSet<String>();
    BundleContext context = Activator.getDefault().getBundle()
            .getBundleContext();
    Bundle[] bundles = context.getBundles();
    PackageAdmin pAdmin = getPackageAdmin(context);

    for (Bundle bundle : bundles) {
        ExportedPackage[] ePackages = pAdmin.getExportedPackages(bundle);
        if (ePackages != null) {
            for (ExportedPackage ePackage : ePackages) {
                packages.add(ePackage.getName());
            }
        }
    }

    return packages;
}

public PackageAdmin getPackageAdmin(BundleContext context) {
    ServiceTracker bundleTracker = null;
    bundleTracker = new ServiceTracker(context,
            PackageAdmin.class.getName(), null);
    bundleTracker.open();
    return (PackageAdmin) bundleTracker.getService();
}
```

Examples of queries and answers in my Eclipse environment:

1. File: [java.io.File, org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.File]
2. List: [java.awt.List, org.eclipse.swt.widgets.List, com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.schemagen.xmlschema.List, java.util.List, org.hibernate.mapping.List]
3. IResource: [org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource]

Answer (score 1):

You probably cannot do this at all. There is no way for the JVM to know whether a class `List` in an arbitrarily named package `a.b.c.d` is available without attempting to load `a.b.c.d.List` first. You would need to test for **all** possible package names.

Answer (score 1):

Without loading them all you could get the classpath property

```
String class_path = System.getProperty("java.class.path");
```

And then you could create a function to search the filesystem for classes in those locations. And you'd have to code it to also search inside jar files, and some of the classes may not *actually* be available due to incompatibilities that would only be revealed when you load them.  But if you just want a best-guess of what's available, this might be viable.  Maybe you should tell us **why** you want to do this so you can get some alternative suggestions?

Edit:
Ok, sounds like you should check out this thread and the ones linked in it: [How do I read all classes from a Java package in the classpath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456930/read-all-classes-from-java-package-in-classpath)
In particular it appears the Spring framework does something similar, maybe you can look at that code: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/core/io/support/PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.html