# Listing classes in a package's subdirectory

Tags: java, android, package, subdirectory

I'm not sure if I'm using the correct terminology here.. but if my package name is set up like this:

```
com.example.fungame
    -ClassA
    -ClassB
    -com.example.fungame.sprite
        -ClassC
        -ClassD
```

How can I programmatically get an array (a `Class[]` I'm guessing) of all the classes in the `.sprite` subdirectory?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. You don't have classes in a directory, you have files. So are you asking how to instantiate the classes that those files represent and place an instance of each in an array?  By the way, even if this is possible, it would likely have to be an `Object[]` unless they shared inheritance from a less general class.

Comment: this question has been asked many times before, one of them is this one: [read all classes from java package in classpath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456930/read-all-classes-from-java-package-in-classpath)

Comment: klactose, I said nothing about instantiating them. And in response to "You don't have classes in a directory, you have files".. where do you think files are located? That's right.. a directory! seanizer, you should post your response as an answer.

Comment: this makes no sense. Packages have sub-packages, not directories. Files are in directories, classes are in packages. There may be zero or more directories corresponding to any given package. And there is certainly no .sprite directory anywhere in your example.

Comment: I think people are missing the first sentence of the post. The only person with a constructive response didn't even post it as an answer so I can upvote/accept it. Ugh.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method:

```
public static Class[] getClasses(String pckgname) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    ArrayList classes=new ArrayList();
    File directory = null;
    try {
        directory = new File(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(pckgname.replace('.', '/')).getFile());
    } catch(NullPointerException x) {
        throw new ClassNotFoundException(pckgname + " does not appear to be a valid package");
    }   
    if (directory.exists()) {
        // Get the list of the files contained in the package
        String[] files = directory.list();
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            // we are only interested in .class files
            if(files[i].endsWith(".class")) {
                // removes the .class extension
                try {
                    Class cl = Class.forName(pckgname + '.' + files[i].substring(0, files[i].length() - 6));
                    classes.add(cl);
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                }
            }
        }   
    } else {
        throw new ClassNotFoundException(pckgname + " does not appear to be a valid package");
    }
Class[] classesA = new Class[classes.size()];
classes.toArray(classesA);
return classesA;
}
```

Comment: I tried this several times, with the subdirectory and even `getPackageName()` but it always throws `ClassNotFoundException`