# java UrlClassLoader: findResources returns null, but loadClass returns classes

Tags: java, jar, urlclassloader

I made as default child of UrlClassLoader, added all my jar files by

```
public void addFile(String path) throws MalformedURLException {
    String urlPath = "jar:file:/" + path + "!/";

    System.out.println("------------------");
    System.out.println("urlPath = " + urlPath);

    URL url = new URL(urlPath);
    System.out.println("url = " + url);
    super.addURL(url);
    System.out.println("g = " + getURLs().length);
    System.out.println("==================");


}
```

then i'm trying to get some class from loader:

```
System.out.println("cl.loadClass() = " + cl.loadClass("com.company.project.SomeClass"));
```

It returns class normally.

When i'm try to find all classes by package:

```
resources = cl.findResources("com/company/");
```

It returns empty enumeration.
Why?

Answer (score 0):

The Java API of `ClassLoader` does not provide a standard way to enumerate all the elements in a package. Since you use your own `ClassLoader`, you can implement a function in it which performs a custom search inside the JARs.

A few links.

Similar question:
[How do I read all classes from a Java package in the classpath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456930/read-all-classes-from-java-package-in-classpath)

How to read a Jar: [How do I list the files inside a JAR file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429172/list-files-inside-a-jar)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `findResources()` does what you think it shuld do. According to [its API doc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html#findResources%28java.lang.String%29):

> Returns an Enumeration of URLs
>   representing all of the resources on
>   the URL search path having the
>   specified name.

That doesn't sound like it would do a prefix match at all (and if you think about it, it would be impossible to do that, given a HTTP URL). What it probably does is look for the given **full name** in all of the base URLs the `URLClassLoader` has been constructed with, so if you call `findResources("log4j.properties")` and the classloader has been constructed with 5 JARs, 3 of which contain a file `log4j.properties` at the root, then the method will return all 3.

Comment: findResources() used for finding all containing information by springframework scanner. There goes right my string to this method.