# Add Annotated Class in Hibernate by adding all classes in some package. JAVA

Tags: java, hibernate

**is there any way to loop (e.g. via for) all classes with are in some package?**
I have to `addAnnotatedClass(Class c)` on `AnnotationConfiguration`.
Doing it like this:

```
    AnnotationConfiguration annotationConfiguration.addAnnotatedClass(AdditionalInformation.class);
    annotationConfiguration.addAnnotatedClass(AdditionalInformationGroup.class);
    annotationConfiguration.addAnnotatedClass(Address.class);
    annotationConfiguration.addAnnotatedClass(BankAccount.class);
    annotationConfiguration.addAnnotatedClass(City.class);
    //et cetera
```

All of my tables are in package `Tables.Informations`.

Comment: by any chance using spring or jpa?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the functionality of loading all classes in a package is not possible with the AnnotationConfiguration API. Here's some of the stuff you can do with said API (note that the "addPackage" method only reads package metadata, such as that found in the package-info.java class, it does NOT load all classes in package):

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/ch01.html

```
sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration()
                    .addPackage("test.animals") //the fully qualified package name
                    .addAnnotatedClass(Flight.class)
                    .addAnnotatedClass(Sky.class)
                    .addAnnotatedClass(Person.class)
                    .addAnnotatedClass(Dog.class)
                    .addResource("test/animals/orm.xml")
                    .configure()
                    .buildSessionFactory();
```

Comment: How on earth does this solve the problem of having to burn in the class names in your utility class? (It only saves a few keystrokes).

Comment: @vbence Yes, agreed, I'm sorry, my answer is wrong: there's no way to add all classes from one package in one go using the AnnotationConfiguration API. The example I give was supposed to illustrate that you can do this, as well as add individual classes and other resources all in one go. I've basicaly had the same misunderstanding on the API as the one discussed here: https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=980723 I wish I could delete my post, but I can't because it's an accepted answer.

Comment: Oh, I read that one (forum post). Maybe you can add a note like *"it is not possible what the OP originnaly wanted, but this syntax helps a little"* or something like that.

Comment: You post is fine, good for me that you didn't delete it :) In fact I found that `addPackage` doesn't have the desired (by me) effect by looking at the hibernate sources first. Then I found your answer which confirms it. This is very inflexibly done in my opinion in hibernate. There should be a method to allow us to load all entity classes from a given package. That functionality is possible if one uses Spring but what if one doesn't use it.

Comment: this is hibernate 3.5 .. how is it done in hibernat 4/5 ?

Comment: @mmm Hibernate 4.3 still doesn't support this. Beyond that I haven't tried this anymore. I prefer using Spring instead (which under the good uses JPA/Hibernate). Spring has some very simple and clear annotations that allows you to pick up entities from a certain package

Comment: I hate Spring. Also requires you to be tied to hard. You can not static void main and get access. I was able to get it to work without spring eventually. not using this.

Answer (score 13):

The following code goes through all the classes within a specified package and makes a list of those annotated with "@Entity".  Each of those classes is added into your Hibernate factory configuration, without having to list them all explicitly.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    try {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
        for (Class cls : getEntityClassesFromPackage("com.example.hib.entities")) {
            configuration.addAnnotatedClass(cls);
        }
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        System.err.println("Failed to create sessionFactory object." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}

public static List<Class<?>> getEntityClassesFromPackage(String packageName) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException, URISyntaxException {
    List<String> classNames = getClassNamesFromPackage(packageName);
    List<Class<?>> classes = new ArrayList<Class<?>>();
    for (String className : classNames) {
        Class<?> cls = Class.forName(packageName + "." + className);
        Annotation[] annotations = cls.getAnnotations();

        for (Annotation annotation : annotations) {
            System.out.println(cls.getCanonicalName() + ": " + annotation.toString());
            if (annotation instanceof javax.persistence.Entity) {
                classes.add(cls);
            }
        }
    }

    return classes;
}

public static ArrayList<String> getClassNamesFromPackage(String packageName) throws IOException, URISyntaxException, ClassNotFoundException {
    ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();

    packageName = packageName.replace(".", "/");
    URL packageURL = classLoader.getResource(packageName);

    URI uri = new URI(packageURL.toString());
    File folder = new File(uri.getPath());
    File[] files = folder.listFiles();
    for (File file: files) {
        String name = file.getName();
        name = name.substring(0, name.lastIndexOf('.'));  // remove ".class"
        names.add(name);
    }

    return names;
}
```

Helpful reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7461653/7255

Answer (score 5):

There is a nice open source package called "org.reflections". You can find it here: https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections

Using that package, you can scan for entities like this:

```java
Reflections reflections = new Reflections("Tables.Informations");
Set<Class<?>> importantClasses = reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(Entity.class);
for (Class<?> clazz : importantClasses) {
    configuration.addAnnotatedClass(clazz);
}
```

Comment: This is great !

Answer (score 2):

You can use **LocalSessionFactoryBuilder** for building session factory that enables you to specify **scanPackages** property.

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(hikariDataSource())
        .scanPackages("com.animals.entities")
        .addProperties(properties)
        .buildSessionFactory();
```

Comment: just to add, this method works only with Spring and not plain Hibernate. I guess if `AnnotationConfiguration` is being used, then OP is using plain Hibernate.