# Hibernate QuerySyntaxException when using annotations for mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-annotations

I have a database table named `USER` and a model class named `User` which is annotated as `@Entity` using `javax.persistence`. When I try to query a user I get the following exception:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Jersey Web Application] in context with path [/myapp] threw exception [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: User is not mapped [FROM User u WHERE u.username = :username]] with root cause
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: User is not mapped
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:171)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementFactory.addFromElement(FromElementFactory.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromClause.addFromElement(FromClause.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:324)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3696)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3585)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:720)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:576)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:313)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:261)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:266)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:153)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:546)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:655)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:679)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:102)
    at com.xxxxxxx.myapp.myapp.sevice.UserService.getUser(UserService.java:32)
    at com.xxxxxxx.myapp.myapp.resources.UserResource.getUser(UserResource.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:205)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Aug 20, 2017 5:29:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFO: Reloading Context with name [/myapp] has started
Aug 20, 2017 5:29:58 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesJdbc
WARNING: The web application [myapp] registered the JDBC driver [org.postgresql.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
Aug 20, 2017 5:29:58 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesThreads
WARNING: The web application [myapp] appears to have started a thread named [pool-2-thread-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
 java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1093)
 java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

My query is in a service class called `UserService.java` which is as below:

```
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

import com.xxxxxx.model.User;

public class UserService {

    private static SessionFactory factory;

    public UserService() {
    }

    public User getUser(String username) {
        try{
            factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) { 
            System.err.println("Failed to create sessionFactory object." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex); 
        }
        Session session = factory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        User user = null;
        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            TypedQuery<User> query = session.createQuery("FROM User u WHERE u.username = :username", User.class).setParameter("username", username);
            user = query.getSingleResult();
        } catch(HibernateException e) {
            if (tx != null) {
                tx.rollback();
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
        return user;
    }

}
```

My model class is below:

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="USER")
public class User {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name="username", unique=true)
    private String username;

    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name="created")
    private Timestamp created;

    public User(long id, String username, String email) {
        this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

For most people who had the same issue it seems that they were using the table name instead of the entity name. However, in my case, I think I'm using the correct entity name. I also tried removing the arguments and body of the constructor of the User but didn't help.

For clarity, below is my `hibernate.cfg.xml`:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>

        <!-- connection settings -->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/myapp</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">admin</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">xxxxx</property>

        <!-- sql dialect -->
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>

        <!-- mapping files -->


        <!-- dev config - remove at prod -->
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: U have non existing mapping section. (mapping xml tag) These are two modes: manual (list classes) or auto. Cant help with details, many years use JPA compatibility level

Comment: The authomatic sequence start with <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" ... and few options

Comment: Oh, which is better, manual or auto? I thought `@Entity` annotation should take care of it...

Comment: swdon probably 'auto' idea is better for You, @Entity and all OK. Belive (have not own benchmark) auto discovering takes more time (once at start). Usually no problem for servlets, not so for destops app (desktop i develop with manually)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, the annotation is not being processed. You either need to create a mapping file and include in your config, https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_mapping_files.htm or as long as I remember there is a way to specify annotation configuration during hibernate session creation where you specify annotated entities. You are probably missing that part. Please, check this for reference [Add Annotated Class in Hibernate by adding all classes in some package. JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8122792/add-annotated-class-in-hibernate-by-adding-all-classes-in-some-package-java)

Comment: I know that I can specify the mapping in the config file. Any idea why `@Entity` is not being used to do the mapping?

Comment: Please, include your code which creates the hibernate session.

Comment: It's in the `UserService` class already included immediately below the stack trace.

Comment: By default, this guy  factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory(); is not going to process annotations. It will expect you to specify the entities in mapping file. If you want to take advantage of annotations, you need to use something like sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration()
                    .addAnnotatedClass(User.class)
                    .configure()
                    .buildSessionFactory();

Comment: Which is better, specify in mapping file or add it as AnnotationConfiguration?

Comment: It is just a matter of preference. But annotations are replacing xml everywhere nowadays. So, it is safe to say annotations. For entities, I like annotations as you can specify the mapping config directly on your entity not in somewhere else.

Comment: swdon adding classes from code is 'the third', very nice (i like java code too) but non-portable to other providers, AFIR internal compatibility between hibernate versions changed too. The "fourth" is very good automatic XML actualisation in IDE (Netbeasn, Eclipse with JPA options I'm sure)