# Load classes from folder without specifying the package

Tags: java, classloader, urlclassloader, dynamic-class-loaders

I have an application that allows, using an abstract class, people to write their own implementations. I load these implementations as .class-files from a directory. Currently, I have this solution:

```
File classDir = new File("/users/myproject/classes/");

URL[] url = { classDir.toURI().toURL() };
URLClassLoader urlLoader = new URLClassLoader(url);

String filename;
for (File file : classDir.listFiles()) {
    filename = string.getFilenameWithoutExtension(file);
    if (filename.equals(".") || filename.equals("..") || filename.startsWith("."))
        continue;

AbstractClass instance = (AbstractClass)urlLoader
    .loadClass("org.mypackage." + filename)
    .getConstructor(ConfigUtil.class, DatabaseUtil.class, StringUtil.class)
    .newInstance(config, database, string));

    instance.doSomething();
}
```

As you see - I need to specify the package the classes are located in in order to correctly load them. Omitting the package, I get an

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
     MyClass (wrong name: org/mypackage/MyClass)
```

error.

Now, from a architectural POV, I think it is very ill-designed that classes other people designed have to be compiled to MY package when loading them.

So I ask you: Is there a way I can load classes form the file system without having to specify the package they reside in?

Comment: You could keep the package structure as a folder structure under your path? And create the package name from the path before loading the class?

Comment: That would be a possibility... At least then I wouldn't have to trouble myself when two classes have the same name... nice thinking from another angle! :)

Comment: Try it and see if it works, if you want some code examples let me know!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes; implement an interface (or use an annotation).

Then use any class-scanning library (there are lots of SO questions about this, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456930/how-do-i-read-all-classes-from-a-java-package-in-the-classpath)) to load the particular class in question. Searching for "Java class scanning" or "Java plugin mechanism" will help.

You might also just want to use the [Java Plugin Framework](http://jpf.sourceforge.net/) and avoid some effort. Although it's not clear to me that it's maintained any more, I know people are still using it.

Comment: I don't think an interface would work correctly (semantically speaking) in my case. The `AbstractClass` has many predefined functions that only use the overridden (passive of override, wtf?) methods of the implementation. An interface doesn't allow that.

Comment: @FlorianPeschka ... same difference.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. What difference of what?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [ServiceProvider](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/jar/jar.html#Service%20Provider)  to load implementations which you don't know.