# wants to execute a java class(which contains main) dynamically from a struts2 web page

Tags: java, struts2

I wanted to create a web page in Struts2.0 which contains a textarea, a property field and submit button. User will enter a java code in this text area and my code will compile it and execute it and will give the result of this code on my property field... the above code works fine in a standalone application. but it does not shows any thing in my web application. plz any one can address it... thanks in advance.

```
package org.controller;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

import java.io.BufferedReader;

import java.io.File;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import java.io.InputStreamReader;



public class JCompilerAction extends ActionSupport 
{


String program;

String MSg;
public JCompilerAction() {
}
public String getProgram() {
    return program;
}
public void setProgram(String program) {
    this.program = program;
}
public String getMSg() {
    return MSg;
}
public void setMSg(String MSg) {
    this.MSg = MSg;
}
public String Compile() {
    try {
        byte[] bFile = program.getBytes();
        File f = new File("D:/nullprog.java");
        FileOutputStream fileOuputStream = new FileOutputStream(f);
        fileOuputStream.write(bFile);
        fileOuputStream.close();
        Process p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("javac  D:/nullprog.java");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p1.getErrorStream()));
        String line = null;
        boolean isError = false;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            MSg = line;
            isError = true;
            return SUCCESS;
        }
        p1.waitFor();
        if (!isError) 
        {
            Process p2 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start nullprog");
            BufferedReader in1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p2.getInputStream()));
            String line1 = null;
            while ((line1 = in1.readLine()) != null) {
                MSg += line1;
            }
            return SUCCESS;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return SUCCESS;
}
public String execute() {
    return SUCCESS;
}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by _does not shows any thing ?_. Please be more descriptive.

Comment: when i write wrong code(syntax error) in my textarea, at that time my compiler code compiles it and displays the respective error message in my property field i.e. MSg in above code, but when i write right syntax then this code does not produce the output... neither it gives any error message in logs... this same code executes well in standalone mode...

Comment: Why don't you try [JavaCompiler API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html)

Comment: can you plz suggest me any sample code... i tried many codes... some of them are working in standalone mode, but when i place them in struts2 appn at that time they dont work... i guess i am not able to implement them in web applications...

Comment: [Here](http://www.javabeat.net/2007/04/the-java-6-0-compiler-api/) is an example of [Java Compiler Api](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html)

Comment: actually i am able to compile the code but unable to execute the code through my java program...

Comment: Java 6.0 Compiler API is useful only to compile the java classes... but what if i wants to execute the java classes which are having main methods through my java program...

Comment: Java 6.0 Compiler API is useful only to compile the java classes... but what if i wants to **execute** the java classes which are having main methods through my java program...  @Apurv

Answer (score 0):

Below is a simple program that first compiles a code and then executes it:

**Executer.java**

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class Executer {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try{
            java.lang.Process p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("javac  MyClass.java");
            p1.waitFor();
            Class<?> c = Class.forName("MyClass");
            Object obj = c.newInstance();
            Method[] mArr = obj.getClass().getMethods();
            for(Method m : mArr){
                if(m.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("main")){
                    m.invoke(obj, new Object[]{new String[]{}});
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**MyClass.java**

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hii");
    }
}
```

For simplicity both the classes are in same package. When I execute Executer class, it first compiles MyClass.java and then runs the main method.

If your requirement is to have the Java files in some folder outside of the project, the to load the compiler class file, you need to follow as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9195661/960778) answer.