# Make all images in a folder into IconImages

Tags: java, jar, embedded-resource, imageicon

I'm trying to figure out how to add a lot of images into my Java program without having to add every file name in the code.

So I want to take all the `.png` images in the correct folder and make them into an `IconImage` and then place them in an `ArrayList`.

What I've got right now is this.

```
private void fillList()
{
    File[] files = new File("C:/Users/marre/Google Drive/Java/lek/imageplay/src/img").listFiles();

    for (File f : files)
    {
        if (f.isFile()) 
        {
                ImageIcon tempIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/img/"+f.getName()));       
                List.add(tempIcon);
        }
    }
}
```

This works the way I want it to regarding getting the names of all images. But the file only reads from absolute file path.

What can I use instead to get the same result, but that works within .jar file (so it reads from `src/img/` and not the whole `c:/ bla bla`..)?

Comment: There is no easy way to do that. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456930/how-do-i-read-all-classes-from-a-java-package-in-the-classpath.

Comment: The best compromise that I've seen is to generate a file that had all the file names of the images in it, load that file (using Class#getResource) and then load the images.  You can create a custom build element to build the file when you compile and build the project

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will be helpful but I had a similar issue in attempting to obtain files within a jar file. In the case this can be useful to you, my approach was to obtain the URL for the files inside the jar using the [`ClassLoader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html):

```
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
URL url = classLoader.getResource("src/img/");
```

Check inside your jar to make sure of the directory structure for the images so you can specify the correct relative path.

Keep in mind, a jar is a packaged form, so this will most likely return a zipped file (and not a simple [File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) object). You might have to dabble in [`ZipFile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html).

```
ZipFile folderInsideJar = new ZipFile(new File(url.getPath());
Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries = folderInsideJar.entries();
while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
     // ideally this would be your image file, zipped
    ZipEntry childFile = entries.nextElement();

    // ... etc ...
}
```

For environments such as JBoss, etc, you might also get virtual files (vfsfile/vfszip). Point being, you can determine what you are dealing with by looking at the result [URL.getProtocol()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#getProtocol%28%29).

It would also appear ImageIcon has a [constructor that takes a URL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#ImageIcon%28java.net.URL%29). You might try giving this a shot to see if it handles the "resource inside jar" case before manually attempting to retrieve the zip file.

Comment: An `ImageIcon` is typically used in a Swing app.  Swing apps. are regularly deployed using [JWS](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) or as applets (or both).  The technique described above will fail for both JWS & applets (even if they are trusted).

Comment: Can you recomend anotherway to achive the same effect? getting all pictuers in the folder inside the program in a format i can work with swing?