# Spring - Jaxb2Marshaller - How to Automatically Add JAXB2 Classes using Annotations

Tags: spring, rest, cxf

I am using Spring 3.1.x and CXF 2.6.1 for REST services. I using jaxbXmlProvider as shown below.

```
<jaxrs:server ...
<jaxrs:providers>
   <ref bean="jaxbXmlProvider" />
</jaxrs:providers>
...
</jaxrs:server>


<bean id="jaxbXmlProvider" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.JAXBElementProvider">
     <property name="jaxbElementClassNames" ref="elements" /> 
</bean>


<util:list id="elements">
    <value>com.model.City</value>
    <value>com.model.Cities</value>
</util:list>
```

I would like to use jaxb2-marshaller for scanning all the POJOS in a package(com.model). Any usage help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can call a method of another bean that provides the list of classes something like:

`<property name="jaxbElementClassNames" value="#{ myBean.classNamesFromPackage}"/>`

Configure myBean that takes package name as a property and has getClassNamesFromPackage method:

`<bean id="myBean" class="x.y.z.MyBean">`
`<property name="packageName" value="com.model" />`
`</bean>`

In getClassNamesFromPackage method of MyBean, you can use the code suggested in [How do I read all classes from a Java package in the classpath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456930/how-do-i-read-all-classes-from-a-java-package-in-the-classpath).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was trying to leverage out of box Spring  jaxb2-marshaller.  <oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="jaxbMarshaller" contextPath="com.example"/> . Not sure how to fit this in CXF

Comment: Refer to following on http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-data-bindings.html: "...Starting from CXF 2.7.2 this will also work well for package-level contexts - add "useSingleContextForPackages" property to get the created single context always used as a packagecontext." I haven't tried it myself but it looks like something you are looking for.