# Find Groovy Class in Source Folder

Tags: grails

I have an Groovy class located in `/src/groovy/` named `testFilter`.
I want to find dynamicly filters, so i tried this:

```
def filterClass = grailsApplication.allClasses.find{it.name==className}
```

but  that doesn't work for files in `/src/groovy/`

how can i find the class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution:

```
def classObject= Class.forName(CLASSNAME, false, Thread.currentThread().contextClassLoader).newInstance()
```

Answer (score 3):

Using grails you can only list domains classes, but you can use java for example : [ClassLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html).

In your case code will be like:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
classLoader.getResource("src")
```

You can also find **answer** on your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456930/how-do-i-read-all-classes-from-a-java-package-in-the-classpath)