# Read all Files from a package in Java

Tags: java

I would love to know how I can read the whole entries from a package in Java. With getRessource() you can get a single file. But I want them all!
My plan is to read all Files from a folder/package (without subdir) and then use a Stream to filter the entries.

Hope you can help me out.

Comment: You read them from a jar? Which is technically a zip file, so you can treat it as thus.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I read all classes from a Java package in the classpath?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456930/how-do-i-read-all-classes-from-a-java-package-in-the-classpath)

Comment: well it is not so much the duplicates, since this topic is regarding the files(resources), however, the other one tackles the classes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can get a list of all the files and then filter them:

```
File d = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")); // user.dir returns the current working directory.

for(File f : d.listFiles())
{
    //do what you want to do
}
```

Comment: This looks nice. Now user.dir gave me all files in my root folder of the project. How can I change the parameter so I get the files in a specific directory like src/test/ressources ?? If I change the parameter like this I get a NullPointerException.

Comment: @SaschaZeller Concatenate it. Use : `new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/src/test/ressources")`

Comment: Oh wow you guys... This answer is full of bad practice. What if your program is packaged as a jar? What if it is launched from outside of its build directory? And why are we concatenating file paths? This completely goes against the spirit of Java, which is write once - run everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using the Spring Framework. Even if you are not developing a Spring application, you can still use their utility methods. You want to use `PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver`:

```
public Resource[] getResources(String package)
{
    PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver pmrpr = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
    // turns com.myapp.mypackage into /com/myapp/mypackage/*
    return pmrpr.getResources("/" + package.replace(".", "/") + "/*");
}
```

For reference, see:

- [`PathMatchinResourcePatternResolver`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/support/PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.html)
- [`AntPathMatcher`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.html)

If you are using Maven, use this dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do so with the [Reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections) library.

One may just create a reflections object and let it do the scanning for you. It would be as easy as doing something like

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections("my.package");
Set<String> resourceStrings = reflections.getResources(s -> true /*match all resources*/);
Set<URL> resources = resourceStrings.stream()
                                    .map(s -> getClass().getResource(s))
                                    .collect(Collectors.toSet())
```