# How to iterate through resource files REGARDLESS of execution from Eclipse or jar

Tags: java, eclipse, executable-jar

I have been given an existing program that works fine in Eclipse and I want to compile it for distribution.  I have no problem in accessing individual resource files both in Eclipse and from a jar.

However, the program iterates through a bunch of files in a folder and I can't figure out how to replicate the logic so it works **both** in Eclipse **and** from a jar.

Some of the original code, as requested:

```
File[] baseFiles = baseFolder.listFiles();
for (int i = 0; i < baseFiles.length; i++) {
    String fileName = baseFiles[i].getName();
    if (!baseFiles[i].isDirectory() && fileName.toUpperCase().endsWith(XML)) {
        // process file
    }
}
```

I tried a few things . . . didn't record them all.  This one gives me an empty enum:

```
    final Enumeration < URL > oneTime = getClass ( )
          .getClassLoader ( )
          .getResources ( basefolder ) ;
```

In response to other comments - in particular whether this is a duplicate of other questions - I have modified the Title to make it clearer

Comment: Can you provide more details? What is the "logic" and what have you tried doing thus far?

Comment: Please show use some code. There are dozens of ways to load files or resources in Java. We cannot help without code (and preferable with some exception).

Comment: And welcome to Stackoverflow!

Comment: The short answer is, it's difficult (and has been asked a number of times before). Essentially, you need to create a text file which contains the path/name of the files in your jar(s). This can built dynamically at build time or you can manage it manually. The at runtime, you would read this file using Class#getResource, now you have a list of the files

Comment: eew!  I'm amazed that this is not standard - after all it should be equally as simple as It is to access a single file as a resource - and that's transparent as to whether you're executing in Eclipse or from a jar.

Comment: What is the error you get? Please update the question with some more details.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463192/reading-content-of-a-jar-file-at-runtime?

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I've seen (and in particular, MadProgrammer's rep) the answer is:

> Essentially, you need to create a text file which contains the
>   path/name of the files in your jar(s). This can built dynamically at
>   build time or you can manage it manually. The at runtime, you would
>   read this file using Class#getResource, now you have a list of the
>   files